# Random Password Generator using Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, password-generator

I am creating a random password generator. 1st i have to ask the user for the length of the password and it must have a minimum of 8 digits to a maximum ​of 16 digits. The one i created is asking the user to key in the password itself and from there its checking the length. First i want the user to key the the length of the password, EG: 7 or 9 or so on. if the user keyed in the digit which is less than 8 and more than 16 it must show "must have a minimum of 8 digits to a maximum of 16 digits". Pls refer below for the code, if its not clear do refer to the both images. thank you.

**INPUT**

```
import random
import string

print('hello, Welcome to Password generator!')

l = False
while not l:
    length = input('\nEnter the length of password: ')
    if len(length) < 8 :
        print('You password length is too short(must be more than 8 character)')
        print(len(length), "is the length of your password")
    elif len(length) > 16:
            print('You password length is too long(must be less than 17 character)')
            print(len(length), "is the length of your password")
    else:
            print('You password length looks good')
            break

lower = string.ascii_lowercase
upper = string.ascii_uppercase
num = string.digits
symbols = string.punctuation

all = lower + upper + num + symbols

temp = random.sample(all,length)

password = "".join(temp)

print(password)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hello, Welcome to Password generator!

Enter the length of password: 9
You password length is too short(must be more than 8 character)
1 is the length of your password

Enter the length of password: 9
You password length is too short(must be more than 8 character)
1 is the length of your password
```

Comment: `l = False` -- using `l` for a variable name is generally a bad idea since it looks too much like `1`.

Comment: We wrote you two answers. If an answer has been useful you can upvote it (you still haven't enough reputation to do it btw). You can also accept an answer to mark it as a working one.

Comment: You explained what you want to do, but what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type for `input()` is `str` or string. When you check the length of the return value, assigned to `length`, it is counting the number of characters in the string and not checking if the given number is greater or smaller than another. To fix the issue, call the integer constructor `int()` on `length` or place it around the call to `input` so that the string is converted into a numeric type before the check.

```
length = int(input('\nEnter the length of password: '))
```

Additionally, since `length` is now an integer, you would perform the check directly without calling `len`. e.g.

```
if length < 8:
    ...
```

Comment: You are right, `int` is a constructor, not a function tecnically. +1

Comment: thank you so much for helping. this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should write this instead:

```
lenght = int(input('insert lenght: '))
```

In Python the `int` built-in function is (also) used to convert a `str` into an integer (`int`) variable.

Then you have to change your code this way:

```
print(lenght, "is the length of your password")
```

---

I would suggest some other improvements.

```
all = lower + upper + num + symbols #Here you are overwriting the all built-in function
```

...or...

```
while True: #Instead of "while not l"
    if (condition_that_will_end_the_loop):
        break
```

---

The built-in `len` function returns an `int`, and is used this way:

```
>>> len([1, 2, 3, 'hey'])
4
>>> len('string')
6
```

Comment: thank you for your guidance. will definitely improve it.